# Comprehension: Consider the $8$ digit number $N=22234000$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Comprehension: Consider the $8$ digit number $N=22234000$.
>   
>   $(1)$ How many possible $8$ digit numbers can be formed using all $8$ digits of $N$?
>   
>   $(a)$ ${8\choose 3}.\frac{5!}{2!}$  $(b)$ ${7\choose 3}.\frac{5!}{2!}$  $(c)$ ${8\choose 3}.\frac{5!}{2!}3!$  $(d)$ ${7\choose 3}.\frac{5!}{2!}3!$
>   
>   $(2)$ A number is randomly chosen out of all possible 8 digit numbers formed using all $8$ digits of $N$. Probability that it will be divisible by $1000$ is-

For the first question I simply did $\frac{8!}{3!3!}=1120$. But it is wrong. Also, for the second one, I did $\frac{20}{1120}=\frac1{56}$. But it is also wrong. So what is the right solution?

Comment: (1) Maybe you cannot start with a zero.

Comment: Oh yea! Thanks, I am so silly! @Element118.

Comment: But how to formulate a number for this condition? @Element118.

Comment: Subtract $\frac{7!}{3! \times 2!}$, which counts the number of ways to  place $0$ at the front.

Comment: Place a $0$ at the front and permute the other $7$ numbers, $3$ of them are 2 and $2$ of them are 0.

Comment: Yea, but aint there any direct method which doesn't involve subtraction? @Element118.?

Comment: Yes there is. You have 5 possible number for the first position. Then you do the same thing you did ending up at $5\frac{7!}{3!3!}$. You can check that this is the same number as Element118 provides.

Comment: But how did you get $3!$ in the denominator? What if we used a $2$ in the beginning? @Marc.

Comment: The total number of ways to arrange the numbers if we dont think about distinction between 2's and 0's is $5\cdot7!$. Each 3! removes the sequences in which twos and zeros are interchanged. Maybe it is intuitively better to include the 5 in the quotient.

Comment: Just for transparency: the numbers cryptically represented in the question are concretely (a) $3360$, (b) $2100$, (c) $20160$, and (d) $12600$. They are all clearly too large, whether  a number is allowed to start with $0$ or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A simple way*

You computed the ans as $1120$.
Just multiply it by $\dfrac58$, the probability that it starts with a non-zero

The ans it yields (which others have also got) is $700$,

the options are definitely wrong.

Comment: One of the most innovative answers I have ever seen!

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments !

Answer (score 0):

8 digit number cant start with 0. Hence:  choose 3 out of 7 for 0s, then 3 out of 5 for 2s, multiply it by 2!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Permute the non-zeroes (5*4), pick $7 \choose 3$ places to insert zeroes: 5*4*35 = 700.

(2) Out of $7 \choose 3$ selections for the zeroes, there is only 1 correct, so $1/35$.